# R function to give group all previous dates when a condition occurs

Tags: r, date

My code is written in R where I have a table existing of 3 variables: a date, an ID and a path. The table is sorted by ID first, then by date. When path is 0, I need to group all previous path numbers for that ID in one line and register the first date (Data_Start) and data where Path = 0 occurred (Date_End). This needs to be done per ID.

For example the second row in the desired result table: path = 0 occurred on 2018-10-08 for ID 5, meaning that all the paths of the previous dates needs to be grouped together as path = 1,0,3,4, Data_Start = 2018-10-05 and Data_End = 2018-10-08.

Source table

```
Date        ID   Path
2018-10-05  5    1
2018-10-06  5    0
2018-10-07  5    3
2018-10-08  5    0
2018-10-06  5    4
2018-10-08  7    5
2018-10-07  8    2
2018-10-08  8    1
2018-10-09  8    0
```

Desired result:

```
Date_Start    Date_End          ID   Index  Path
2018-10-05    2018-10-06        5    1      1,0
2018-10-05    2018-10-08        5    2      1,0,3,0
2018-10-06    2018-10-06        5    3      4
2018-10-08    2018-10-08        7    4      5
2018-10-07    2018-10-09        8    5      2,1,0
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Along with `ID`, we can create another group where `Path` becomes 0, get the `first` and `last` `Date` of each group. To get all the previous `Path` numbers we check if the last value ends with 0 and also `replace` their `Date_Start` with the `first` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(group = lag(cumsum(Path == 0), default = 0)) %>%
   group_by(ID, group) %>%
   summarise(Date_Start = first(Date), 
             Date_End = last(Date), 
             Path = toString(Path)) %>%
   mutate(Path = paste_values(Path), 
          Date_Start = replace(Date_Start,endsWith(Path,"0"),first(Date_Start))) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    dplyr::select(-group) %>%
    mutate(Index = row_number())

#    A tibble: 5 x 5
#     ID Date_Start Date_End   Path       Index
#  <int> <fct>      <fct>      <chr>      <int>
#1     5 2018-10-05 2018-10-06 1, 0           1
#2     5 2018-10-05 2018-10-08 1, 0, 3, 0     2
#3     5 2018-10-06 2018-10-06 4              3
#4     7 2018-10-08 2018-10-08 5              4
#5     8 2018-10-07 2018-10-09 2, 1, 0        5
```

where I define `paste_values` function as

```
paste_values <- function(value) {
  sapply(seq_along(value), function(x) {
     if (endsWith(value[x], "0")) toString(value[1:x])
     else value[x]
   })
}
```